# Quotient of hyperbolic disc model

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, teichmueller-theory

I am trying to learn decorated Teichmüller theory and reading Penner's "Decorated Teichmüller Theory" book.  In Chapter 2 in "Punctured Surfaces" section I got confused.

Let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the Poincare disc model of the hyperbolic surface. Let $\Gamma$ denote Fuchsian group. He wrote:

"Suppose that $x \in S_{\infty}$
is the fixed point of some parabolic transformation
in $\Gamma$ acting on $\mathbb{D}$. A horocycle in the hyperbolic plane centered at $x$ projects into
the surface $F=\mathbb{D}/\Gamma$ to a closed curve in $F$ , and we refer to such a curve as a horocycle
in $F$ , which is possibly immersed but not embedded; we say that the horocycle
is centered at the puncture of $F$ corresponding to $x$."

I don't understand why a horocycle in $\mathbb{D}$ becomes a closed curve in $\mathbb{D}/\Gamma$? why can't it intersect itself?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is unclear. The closed curve *can* intersect itself; that's what it means to say that it is "possibly immersed but not embedded".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can't say I fully understand though. Can you explain a bit more please? Also, is it obvious that a horocycle is a curve in the quotient? Thank you.

Comment: To improve your question, perhaps you could explain more about what you *do* understand in this passage. Without that, its hard to know where to start. For instance, your last comment indicates to me that you may not understand that this passage is discussing and comparing two distinct concepts: a "horocycle in the hyperbolic plane" versus a "horocycle in $F$".

Comment: I am sorry for not being very precise. I should have written more explicity. What I quote from the book is the definition of the horocycle in F. So, yes I am trying to understand what does a horocycle in F mean. In the definition there are two things I don't see. First one is:  why a horocycle becomes a curve in the quotient \mathbb{D}/\Gamma? The second is the remark "possibly immersed but not embedded". I understand from your first comment that if it is immersed then it can intersect itself but if it were embedded than it cannot intersect itself.